# iTunes app min version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have iOS app in iTunes with min supported version iOS 8.0; if I now update my app with new build with minimum version of iOS 10.0, will it be possible to users on iOS devices with iOS 8.0 to access previous version of my app?

Comment: yes, that happens exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

Never tried it, but it's possible according to - 
http://mashable.com/2013/09/17/ios-legacy-apps/#3QSWoGqLEkqQ

Comment: could you please provide any links? if there any

Answer (score 1):

Go over to iTunes Connect > My App > the App > App Store > Pricing and Availability

At the very bottom you should see the Heading "Last-Compatible Version Settings". Click on the "All" as seen on my screenshot. There you can basically enable or disable the "old" version of your app.

[image]

You can also find some words in the official docs over here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW3